# Uber Question : Toggle a cell from 0 to 1 to get the optimum path

Tags: grid, dynamic-programming

In a Binary maze with 0 and 1, 0 is the valid cell to which we can travel and 1 means that the cell is blocked. Given source and destination. We have to find- 
1. IF path exists, if yes, find shortest path. 
2. If we are given a chance to toggle single cell from 1 to 0 , which cell you will toggle so that you will surely get the shortest path.

For the second part how to check for each of the cell without toggling it one by one, if there any efficient way to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using a dynamic programing approach where you at any index i of the grid take the min of the all possible direction you can take, you can use a greedy approach where you create the graph in such a way that a index i is connected to all the indexes around it(max possible 8) in the grid which has zero value and use the shortest path algorithm between given two nodes. This will make toggling also easy you only toggle the set of indexes which are shared between the source and the destination.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I actually solved it using a bfs containing 3 fileds , the cell position x and y and the number of toggle cells done so far. For each cell explore the adjacent cells , if encountered a blocked cell increase the toggle count for the subsequent ones. BFS would ensure the shortest path at the end.